# Which quantum gate/gates can be used to load classical data into a quantum register controlled by other qubit values?

Tags: quantum-computing

I have two quantum registers, both consisting of one qubit (aiming to extend it to more once I understand it better)
A Hadamard gate is applied to the first register resulting in an equal superposition of 0 and 1.

|00> -> (|0>+|1>)|0> (with factor of 1/ squareroot(2))

I would like to apply a quantum gate to the second register with the first register as the control so that different information is encoded when the first register is 0 than when the first register is 1. I am not sure how to achieve this.

I looked at controlled U gates, but it does not seem to be what I need.

Another issue that I am facing is that the information that needs to be encoded in the second register is stored classically (outputs from a classical function) so I am not sure how to combine the classical and quantum parts.

Thanks for any help/suggestions! (Apologies for the equation formatting)